# How can I deal with child route with params in angular 2?

Tags: url, angular, routes, components

When i'm in my VideoComponent my URL looks like that : `app/video/9`

Here is the problem, i want to reach my EditComponent 
when i click to a tag (with routerLink) and rewrite my url like that : `app/video/9/users/3`

This is my route config :

```
@RouteConfig([      
    { path: '/video/:video_id/users/:user_id', component: Edit, name: 'Edit'},
    { path: '/video/:video_id/', component: Video, name: 'Video'}
)]
```

And finally my routerLink :

```
[routerLink]=" ['Edit',{user_id:1}]"
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: This looks like you are using an old and deprecated router version. Any reason you're not using the newest router?

Comment: Angular 2 RC1... i'm working on a admin dashboard template, not updated yet.

Comment: What is not working? Where is your `routerLink`. Maybe you just need to prefix the route name with `../` or `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just forgot directives in my child EditComponent :

```
directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink]
```